# Clotted cream broke in the fridge

Tags: turkish-cuisine, clotted-cream

Yesterday, I purchased a package of Kaymak (the Turkish version of Devonshire clotted cream). Normally, it would act just like clotted cream. It was in the fridge when I purchased it and looked fine. I put it in the fridge at home, and it broke. Now, it's just a container of thick cream.

Why would that have happened? Can I rescue it? (Maybe use the cream and try to heat again?)

Comment: ah, what do you mean by "broke"?  Because "it broke" and "just cream now" are pretty opposite.  Clotted cream is, unless I misremember, thick, partially dehydrated and fermented cream.  I can imagine no transformation that would lead this to convert back into cream (there isn't enough *liquid*, and unfermenting is...not *likely*).  If you mean the product looks like it tried to crack and weep - as long as it smells good I would try just mixing it back together, like with yogurt, and see if that fixes it.  If it just looks liquid check the flavor, maybe this style or brand is just thinner.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about the breaking of emulsion. The solution is to simply whip it again, a food processor should also be fine for Kaymak.

Comment: I would wonder if pH went down to cause the break. Give it a smell and a taste before proceding.